# How do you block someone on Facebook without their username?

Tags: facebook

So recently, somebody blocked me on Facebook. When I found this out, I got their profile ID. However, my friend checked if he had a username but he didn't.

Normally, I know how to block someone if they blocked me.

1. Type in their username.
2. Press block when a popup box shows up.

However, I tried to type in the profile ID but it didn't show up. How do I block that person?

Comment: If they blocked you, why do you want to block them back? I'm not sure if the person who blocks you can even see your profile anymore, like it's a mutual block...unless I'm wrong?

Comment: Possible stalking reasons. No they don't get to see your profile but still, this can result in stalking. Basically, you're not allowing the person who got blocked to see anything but in case you unblock them at any given point, you can steal the public information. That's why it's best to block them back.

Comment: You can the person's email address instead of their username, if you happen to have that. Otherwise, if it's a stalking problem, consider reporting the person to Facebook.